# Codesigning GDB issues on MacOS Catalina

Tags: gdb, code-signing, macos-catalina, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I've been trying to set up gdb on my Macbook Pro 13" 2020, running MacOS Catalina v 10.15.5

I've followed multiple tutorials on codesigning GDB to little luck. Here's a link to one of the tutorials I;ve followed, though I've tried others where taskgated is closed via the terminal. [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html)

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the command I'm running to code sign:

```
codesign -fs gdb /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

Where gdb is the name of the certificate and `which gdb` returns /usr/local/bin/gdb

Every time I try to run GDB, it gives the error:

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 1398: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Finally, I tried adding `set startup-with-shell off` to ~/.gdbinit, to similar results.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 with Catalina

I just followed the guide to install and code sign GDB, all went well.
first couple attempts I got the same output, than I ran gdb as sudo and it worked. My next problem is unhandled dyld version 16, seems to be a error upstream with GDB

Comment: The problem wasn't upstream GDB. Apple made a silent change that requires lldb to be signed by the root user. The root user can be enabled through the Directory Utility.